# How it is supposed to get the changed data from the linked enpoint to a webhook at frontend- React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webhooks

I have a webhook that is linked to endpoint `/webhook/payment-transactions`. I know the webhook works as expected, the dashboard that I use for webhooks shows a data when a payment status changes. But I need to use this data-info for my React app. The flow is like : user gives the info that payment API requires, does the payment, the payment is done, waits at a page that shows the status of the payment that was just done.

How can I achieve getting this data in React using for example Fetch API? Should I create a GET request route for the API that I use for subscription of webhook (I mean the API that has the route `/webhook/payment-transactions` )

I searched through the internet to see if someone had done something with React and a webhook but unfortunately, there are lots of stuff that the websites that provides creating webhooks prepared blog posts. Those were backend like blogposts and they never mention about how to get the changed data from frontend.